# how to iterate from index n to m of an OrderedDict?

Tags: python, iteration, ordereddictionary

I have an `OrderedDict` and I would like to iterate over a subset of its elements, from index `n` to `m`.I can do it the simple way:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
for i in range(10):
    d[i] = i

n = 3
m = 6
c = 0
for i in d:
    if n <= c <= m:
        print(d[i])
    c += 1
```

but I was looking for something more compact, similar to slicing for lists:

```
n = 3
m = 6
l = [i for i in range(10)]
for i in l[n:m+1]:
    print(i)
```

Is there such a mechanism for `OrderedDict`?

Comment: Why isn't your *"compact"* example `l[n:m+1]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: should be! I will correct that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your `OrderedDict` is created (`n` and `m` need to consider the index of the items in `d`), but how about this:

```
d.values()[n:m]
```

Comment: @bereal Because of `for i in d:`

Comment: @Kasra he is printing `d[i]`, that's what he needs.

Comment: @bereal Yeah OP wants the value but doesn't check the value within range! any way the question is not clear!

Comment: @Kasra: can you please elaborate on *the question is not clear*?

Comment: @WoJ Ah sorry i missed the *index*! this answer is correct!

Comment: For Python3 this will be `list(d.values())[n:m]`